# how to loop through an xmlHttp request array

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Am having this array receive the response of an xmlHttp Request as shown below:
          var response =xmlHttp.responseText; 
and then i display the variable "response" using an alert and this is  the result

```
  Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [username] => coder
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [username] => dav
)
```

i wanted to loop through this variable "response" such that i can get two columns id and username with their respective data..

Am really having problems with this...Any help will be highly appreciated..Thanks in advance